# How to Call a .Net Web Service Method from Classic ASP Using SOAP

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, asp-classic

I am trying to call a .Net Web Service from Classic ASP using SOAP.  I have built the following code as a test and keep getting back an empty reponsebody with a 400 Bad Request error.  Am I doing something wrong or might this issue be on the .Net side?

```
'set up xmlhttp to checkout server
Dim oRequest
Set oRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

'setting this option will allow ServerXMLHTTP to ignore the certificate errors it encounters.
oRequest.setOption(2) = SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS


' resolve, connect, send, receive - in milliseconds
oRequest.setTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000

'set the URL
msURL = "[redacted]"

msSOAP = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap12=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"">"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<SOAP:Body>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<[Some Service] xmlns=""http://localhost"">"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<MethodName>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<methodParam1>[some value]</methodParam1>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<methodParam2>[some value]</methodParam2>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<methodParam3>[some value]</methodParam3>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "</MethodName>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "</[Some Service]>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "</SOAP:Body>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "</soap12:Envelope>"

oRequest.Open "POST", msURL, False
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPMethodName", "[MethodName]"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "[Some Url]"
oRequest.send msSOAP

Response.Write oRequest.ResponseBody
```

Comment: Oops.  I see the poorly formatted XML with the soap12 tag that doesn't match the SOAP end tag.  But, that doesn't matter.  It's correct in the real version of my code with no good results.

Comment: What type (and format) is `<statusDateTime/>` and does it match what you get from `Now()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution was the answer to my problem.  And Filburt, once I actually made a good SOAP call, I discovered that you're question was highly legitimate.  The type and format mattered greatly!

```
'set up xmlhttp to checkout server
Dim oRequest
Set oRequest = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

'setting this option will allow ServerXMLHTTP to ignore the certificate errors it encounters.
oRequest.setOption(2) = SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS

' resolve, connect, send, receive - in milliseconds
oRequest.setTimeouts 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000

'set the URL
msURL = "[Service Url]"

msSOAP = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<s:Body>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<[MethodName] xmlns=""[Some Namespace]"">"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "<methodParam1>[Some value]</methodParam1>"
 msSOAP = msSOAP & "<methodParam2>[Some value]</methodParam2>"
 msSOAP = msSOAP & "<methodParam3>[Some value]</methodParam3>"
   msSOAP = msSOAP & "</MethodName>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "</s:Body>"
msSOAP = msSOAP & "</s:Envelope>"

oRequest.Open "POST", msURL, False
oRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
oRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "[Some Url]"
oRequest.send msSOAP
```

I took the "?wsdl" off of the url and changed the envelope a bit and it works now.  I also removed the setting of the SoapMethodName header.

Comment: Removing `?wsdl` and whether `localhost` is really your schema namespace would have been my next questions ;-)